# Eclipse RCP: Common Navigator - open file on double click

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP application for which I need to create a file browser view. I want to pass it a root (some location on the local computer) and the view should populate all the files and folders at that location. Currently I am using CNF in my view hence,

```
public class CurrDirExplorerView extends CommonNavigator
```

I have overriden the `getInitialInput()` to return a custom root object which contains a directory path in it. I am using `java.io.File` since `IResources` are linked to the workspace. I have created an element object which is like a wrapper class for the `java.io.File` and returns the name etc for supporting the label and content providers. My view displays all the folders and files at the location specified in my root object but since they are not `IResources`, when I double-click on a file, it does not open up in the editor.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

CommonNavigator has a protected method:

protected void handleDoubleClick(DoubleClickEvent anEvent);

unfortunatelly its javadoc says "This method is for internal use only", however still avail if there is no better option.

Other way would be: getCommonViewer(), which has addDoubleClickListener() and you will be able to define your own logic for handling doubleclick. Hope this helps.

Comment: Where would I place the getCommonViewer().addDoubleClickListener()? I would like to do it the correct way and I do not want to use any internal use only methods.

Comment: I would try

@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite aParent) {
super.createpartControl(aParent);

getCommonViewer()....
}

Comment: If I am overriding the createPartControl, then isn't it better if I use TreeViewer instead of the CNF?

Comment: Short answer: ProjectExplorer does the same, overrides createPartControl. Long answer: I don't know exactly what you are trying to do with the "double click". The normal way in eclipse when you want to associate an editor with a certain file(type) is to contribute to org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes (conent-type with its id + file-association). In your case file-extensions could be '*', your editor could be built-in TextEditor.
You will have to add a contentTypeBinding to your editor declared in the plugin xml. it may worth looking for these "buzzwords" I mentioned.

Comment: Yes that works if your CNF is associating IResources, hence I mentioned that I am using java.io.Files as my view should not have any relation with the workspace. As far as I understand, IResources are linked to a workspace.

Answer (score 1):

There is a global Preference (see picture) that is used by the Navigator. If you want to preset this preference you have to set the preference key (boolean) `OPEN_ON_SINGLE_CLICK` in the preferencestore of bundle `org.eclipse.ui.workbench`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that is unfortunately not what I am looking for. I have created my own view that extends the common navigator and since I am using java.io.file and NOT an IResource, I need to manage the opening of files on my own.